# The show technical items button is missing

Tags: software-center

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 vivid i386. In the software center the option to show technical items is missing? I have no idea what to do.

Comment: What is the option "to show technical items"? I've never seen such option in Ubuntu.

Comment: never seen one..

Comment: If a software list view has items hidden by default, the bottom of the pane containing the view should have a panel (below the bottom of the scrollbar) containing a hyperlink of the form “Show 17 technical items”. Following the link should display the items that were hidden by default, and make the link change to the form “Hide 17 technical items”. Except in Back/Forward navigation, revisiting the software list view should not persist in showing items; it should resume hiding them by default.[https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter)

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score -2):

I updated Ubuntu using the Software Updater and rebooted. I repeated this a few times. I tried again opening the Software & Updates app and on the first tab 'Ubuntu Software' I changed Download from: Server for United States to Main Server. I updated again. No change.

Then I changed back to Server for United States. I tried looking for the 'Show technical items' to appear at the bottom of Software Center screen after searching for xfce4. I still did not see it appear.

When I returned to the laptop I tried searching for xfce4 in the Ubuntu Software Center and low and behold it presented 'Show 71 technical items at the bottom of the screen. Perhaps the laptop needed to be left alone to finish downloading information from the servers after the fresh install.